# How to insert tag in xml file

Tags: java, android

I have a XML document, i want to insert more number of tag. example 
`<data>
               <tag1>1St tag</tag1>
               <tag2>2nd tag</tag2>
               <tag3>NewTag</tag3>
<tag4>4th tag</tag4>
            </data>`

I have tried to insert the data, but whenever i insert the data the inserting element occurred at once

```
DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(); 
            domFactory.setIgnoringComments(true);
            DocumentBuilder builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder(); 
            Document doc = builder.parse(new File("File.xml")); 

            NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("tag4");

            Text a = doc.createTextNode("value"); 
            Element p = doc.createElement("tag3"); 
            p.appendChild(a); 



             for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
                 nodes.item(i).getParentNode().insertBefore(p, nodes.item(i));
        }
            Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");

            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new StringWriter());
            DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
            transformer.transform(source, result);

            String xmlOutput = result.getWriter().toString();
            System.out.println(xmlOutput);
        System.out.println("Done");
```

This code is adding new element but whenever i insert new tag it rewrite the new tag name into existing tag. How to rectify the issue. To be simple i want to insert more tag in XML file.

Comment: your `nodes.getLength()` in `for loop` is not getting refreshed after insert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Add a text node to the element
element.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("D"));

// Add a text node to the beginning of the element
element.insertBefore(doc.createTextNode("A"), element.getFirstChild());

// Add a text node before the last child of the element
element.insertBefore(doc.createTextNode("C"), element.getLastChild());

// Add another element after the first child of the root element
Element element2 = doc.createElement("item");
element.insertBefore(element2, element.getFirstChild().getNextSibling());

// Add a text node in front of the new item element
element2.getParentNode().insertBefore(doc.createTextNode("B"), element2);
```

Sample piece of code which will be helpful for you to add